# Testing Python methods call sequence in a multithreaded context

Tags: python, multithreading, unit-testing, mocking, tdd

I need to check the sequence of calling of some methods of a class.
I had this need while I was developing using TDD (**test driven development**), so when I was writing the test for `method_1()` I would like to be sure that it calls some methods in an precise order.

I suppose that my production `class A` is stored in the following file *class_a.py*:

```py
class A:
    __lock = None

    def __init__(self, lock):
        self.__lock = lock

    def method_1(self):
        self.__lock.acquire()
        self.__atomic_method_1()
        self.__lock.release()

    def __atomic_method_1(self):
        pass
```

The `__lock` attribute is an instance of class `threading.Lock` and is use to reach a thread safe execution of `__atomic_method_1()`.

I need to write a unit test that checks the sequence of calling of the methods of the `class A` when it is invoked the `method_1()`.

The check must verify that `method_1()` calls:

1. as first method: `self.__lock.acquire()`
2. after that it calls `self.__atomic_method_1()`
3. the last method called is `self.__lock.release()`

*My need comes from wanting to make sure that the `__atomic_method_1()` method runs in a multithreaded context without being interrupted.*

### A useful hint but not enough

[This is](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31913232/how-to-unittest-the-sequence-of-function-calls-made-insde-a-fuction-python) a very useful link, but it doesn't solve my problem. The solution provided by the link is perfect to verify the calling order of a sequence of functions invoked by an other function. The link shows an example where the function under test and the functions called are all contained in a file called `module_under_test`.
In my case, however, I have to verify the calling sequence of methods of a class and this difference prevents to use the solution provided by the link.

### A trace that starts from the suggestion

However I have tried to develop the unit test referring to [the link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31913232/how-to-unittest-the-sequence-of-function-calls-made-insde-a-fuction-python) and in this way I have prepared a trace of the test file that I can show below:

```py
import unittest
from unittest import mock
from class_a import A
import threading

class TestCallOrder(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_call_order(self):
       # create an instance of the SUT (note the parameter threading.Lock())
       sut = A(threading.Lock())

       # prepare the MOCK object
       source_mock = ...
       with patch(...)

           # prepare the expected values
           expected = [...]

           # run the code-under-test (method_1()).
           sut.method_1()

           # Check the order calling
           self.assertEqual(expected, source_mock.mock_calls)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

But I'm not able to complete the method `test_call_order()`.

Thanks

Comment: I don't think this is a good use of unit testing.  Unit tests of methods should be black box affairs.  Test method_1, not its implementation.

Comment: What is insufficient about the first answer from your link? It seems to be exactly what you need.

Comment: @duffymo I agree with you and in general I don't do a similar test. In this case I want to be sure that the method `acquire()` and `release()` of the class threading.Lock are called as first and last. This ensures that the instructions inside `__atomic_method_1()` are thread safe.

Comment: @jprebys The link works if the functions are not methods of a class. The idea of the link is perfect, but I'm not able to use it in exactly my task. If someone can adapt the info inside the link to my class I would be grateful.

Comment: I wouldn't go that far.  Just my opinion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the question's comments they said that it is not what unit tests are for. Yes, that makes for a brittle tests. But they serve a real use : do I correctly implement locking. You may want to refactor your class so that it is easier to test (and that would be another interesting question).

But if you really want to test it, as is, I have a solution for you.

What we need is to **spy** on the three methods `self.__lock.acquire`, `self.__lock.release` and `self.__atomic_method_1`. One way to do it is to wrap a Mock around them, and record the behavior. But just knowing they were called is not sufficient, you want the order between them. So you need multiple spies, which collectively log the actions that took place.

```py
import unittest
from unittest import mock
from class_a import A
import threading

class TestCallOrder(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_call_order(self):
        sut = A(threading.Lock())

        # bypass the "name mangling" due to leading "__"
        sut_lock = sut._A__lock
        sut_method = sut._A__atomic_method_1

        # store what we observed during the test
        observed = []

        # prepare the side effects : they are simply observing the call, then forwarding it to the actual function
        def lock_acquire_side_effect():
            observed.append("lock acquired")
            sut_lock.acquire()
        def lock_release_side_effect():
            observed.append("lock released")
            sut_lock.release()
        def method_side_effect(*args, **kwargs):
            observed.append("method called")
            sut_method(*args, **kwargs)

        # prepare the spies, one on the lock, one on the method
        # (we could also mock the two Lock methods separately)
        lock_spy = mock.Mock(wraps=sut_lock, **{"acquire.side_effect": lock_acquire_side_effect,
                                                "release.side_effect": lock_release_side_effect})
        method_spy = mock.Mock(wraps=sut_method, **{"side_effect": method_side_effect})
        # they are wrapping the actual object, so method calls and attribute access are forwarded to it
        # but we also configure them, for certain calls, to use a special side effect (our spy functions)
        with mock.patch.object(sut, "_A__lock", lock_spy):
            with mock.patch.object(sut, "_A__atomic_method_1", method_spy):
            # we apply both spies (with Python 3.10 you can do it with only one `with`)
                sut.method_1()
                self.assertEqual(["lock acquired", "method called", "lock released"], observed)
                # and we check against a very nice ordered log of observations

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

---

## **Edit**

To explain better what I did, here is a schema of how *things* are connected without mocks :

[image: before mocking]

Your SUT has two references :

- one named `__locked` which points to its `Lock` instance, which itself has (for our concerns) 2 references : `acquire` and `release`
- the other named `__atomic_method_1` which points to its `A.__atomic_method_1` method

What we want is to observe the calls made to `__lock.acquire`, `__lock.release`, `__atomic_method_1` and their relative order.

The simpler way to do that I could think of is to replace each of these three by "spy functions", which records they were being called (simply by appending in a list) then forward the call to the actual function.

But then we need these functions to be called, so we will have to mock things. Because they are not "importable", we can't [`mock.patch`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#unittest.mock.patch) them. But we have the actual object we want to mock things of, and that is exactly what [`mock.patch.object`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#unittest.mock.patch.object) is for ! While in the `with`, the `sut.something` will get replaced by a mock. So we need two mocks, one for the `__atomic_method_1`, the other for `__lock`.

As far as I can tell, we won't use `__atomic_method_1` in any other way than calling it. So we just want our mock to call our spy method instead. To do that, we can [`configure`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#unittest.mock.Mock.configure_mock) it to call a function when it gets called, indicated by `"side_effect"`.

But there are many other ways we can use our `__lock` besides `acquire`-ing and `release`-ing it. We don't know what the `__aotmic_method_1` will do with it. So to be sure, we will set the mock to forward everything to the actual object, which means it `wraps` it.

Which gives us this :

[image: after mocking]

The calls to `__lock.acquire` and `__lock.release` are sort of diverted (thanks to mocking) through our spy, while any other still gets through ordinarily.

<sub>(We could have done without creating a Mock for `__aotmic_method_1`, and `mock.patch.object` with the spy function)</sub>

Comment: It works perfectly but I have to study it before accept the answer. But for me is very useful. For now I can only Upvote for it. Sorry your knowledge are much higher than mine..

Comment: @frankfalse I added an explanation with colorful schemas :) Hope it gets clearer this way. But indeed mocking can get hard when we want to do subtle things like this. I used to struggle, it takes time to master mocks.

Comment: Thank you very much. Your explanation is so clear that "I'm forced" to accept your anwser. I need to study the instruction `mock.Mock(wraps=sut_method, **{"side_effect": method_side_effect})` because I don't understand it. If you want to add a brief example about it in the answer I would be grateful. I have found an other solution to my problem and after I have accepted your answer I add my **poor solution**. If you want, please, add some comments to it.

Comment: For this particular instruction, I recommend you read the [`mock.Mock` doc](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#unittest.mock.Mock), it explains what `wraps` does, and that it accepts "arbitrary keyword arguments" to [`configure_mock`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#unittest.mock.Mock.configure_mock) further. The syntax is a bit strange for it, I could have simple done `Mock(side_effect=method_side_effect)` but it wouldn't have worked for the other, you cant do `Mock(release.side_effect=lock_release_side_effect)`. Is it clearer ?

Comment: It's clear. I have to read the documentation. Thank you very much.

Comment: I have studied the instruction `sut_spy = mock.Mock(wraps=sut, **{...})` and I have created some useful tests to use it. I have read [this documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#unittest.mock.Mock) but it isn't so clear for me. Better write some examples starting from the code of your answer. One question: I didn't know, before your example, the used of the notation **{'key': 'value'} inside the call of a method, but only in the definition of a method. I think I don't know something about Python notations. Can you help me? I have to write a new question?

Comment: @frankfalse The `mock.Mock` function accepts **kwargs**, which are arbitrarily-named arguments, and acts upon them. For example if you give it `foo=4`, then it will set the returned Mock to have a `foo` field whose value is `4` (cf `configure`). I want it to answer to `acquire.side_effect`, but the Python syntax does not let me write `acquire.side_effect=lock_acquire_side_effect` in a function call, because `acquire` does not exist. So I use `**` to pass a dictionnary directly, whose keys will be the named parameters, cf [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21809112/11384184).

Comment: Thank you: your last comment and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21809112/what-does-tuple-and-dict-mean-in-python) are enough to add more comprehension on passing dictionary with the operator `**` to a function and how you have used this operator in your test code.

Answer (score 1):

The solution of @Lenormju is obviously rich of concepts about Mocking and, in my opinion, is preferable than this. In fact I have accepted it.
However I propose an other answer that can be used to solve some testing problem and my specific test case.

The test method that I have written is based on the following ideas:

1. create a Mock instance by the method `mock.create_autospec()`:

```
mock_a = mock.create_autospec(A)
```

2. invoke the method `method_1()` by the class `A` (**Class Attribute references**) and passing it the Mock instance:

```
A.method_1(mock_a)
```

The complete test file is the following:

```py
import unittest
from unittest import mock
from class_a import A

class MyTestCase(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_call_order(self):
        mock_a = mock.create_autospec(A)
        expected = [mock.call._A__lock.acquire(),
                    mock.call._A__atomic_method_1(),
                    mock.call._A__lock.release()]
        A.method_1(mock_a)
        self.assertEqual(expected, mock_a.mock_calls)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

### The test doesn't use an instance of the class under test

One of the problem of this test is that it doesn't create an instance of `class A` and so it invokes `method_1()` in a different way respect of the production code.

On the other hand this is a specific test that I have to use to check the static structure of the `method_1()` code so, in my opinion and only in this specific case, the *trick* could be acceptable.

Comment: Indeed, my solution is way more complex than yours. The main difference is that mine spies on the calls, while yours completely mocks them. You don't test at all what the `__atomic_method_1` does, if it were to (accidentally) do `lock.__release` your test wouldn't see it, and pass. But if you just want to make extra sure that `method_1` do these the three expected things in the expected order, then your solution is much more fit than mine to the problem, I just didn't understand the focus was so narrow. Glad you found a nice way ! :)

Comment: @Lenormju I think I will have other similar problems with testing in the future, so I hope you will provide this level of support to me and anyone else who needs it. A thousand thanks.